# how to edit values in table cells to update to database

Tags: jquery

I have table with database. Here the code with table: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hsXRf/9/)
I want to click on the cell that I want to update the value.
the cell should have class like below:

```
.edittd
{
 display:none
}
```

after clicking on the cell
the class will be:

```
.edittd
{
font-size:14px;
width:200px;
background-color:#ffffcc;
border:solid 1px #000;
padding:4px;
}
```

this will make the cell more bigger and more Conspicuous.

then after entering the new value and clicking outside the field it gets updated.

I tried to do it like below:

```
$('tr').click(function(){ 
    $('#display').html(this.id); 
    $('td',this).attr('class').toggleClass('edittd');
});​
```

also I don't know how to convert regular cell(td) to input field and revert back to regular cell after updating.

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML code...

```
<tr id="5" class="edit_tr">
<td width="50%" class="edit_td">
<span id="first_5" class="text" style="display: inline; ">Priyank</span>
<input type="text" value="Priyank" class="editbox" id="first_input_5" style="display:    none; ">
</td>
<td width="50%" class="edit_td">
<span id="last_5" class="text" style="display: inline; ">Patel</span> 
<input type="text" value="Patel" class="editbox" id="last_input_5" style="display: none;  ">
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".edit_tr").click(function(){
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    $("#first_"+ID).hide();
    $("#last_"+ID).hide();
    $("#first_input_"+ID).show();
    $("#last_input_"+ID).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the td, which woud invalidate your markup, just add an inputfield as child.

To give you a startingpoint, I edited your **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/87KHY/1)**

After saving, you remove the input field and the class `edittd`.

Note: The correct call to toggle a class is: `$('td').toggleClass('edittd');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin like : **[PLUGIN](http://www.labs.mimmin.com/inlineedit/#demo)**

OR

Plugin no 2 : [Link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-inline-editor/)

```
$('table.myTable').inplacerowedit({


    url: /Some/URL',
        inputs: {
            '0': { type: 'datepicker', name: 'OpenDate' },
            '1': { type: 'datepicker', name: 'CloseDate' },
            '2': { type: 'text', name: 'Cost' },
            '3': { type: 'text', name: 'Description' }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('td').click(function(e){
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<input class="edited" type="text" value="' + txt + '" />');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found selution.
The selution contain two element on the cell(td tag).
1 - one element is span.
2 - secend element is input field.
normal mode the span is visable and the input field is hiden.
edit mode we opposite the atribute of the alemnt which it is mean the span is hiden and the input field is display.
link for the selution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Tu2eE/4/)
you should click on the cel name 'colume1' after that you can edit it.
when you finsh you can click outside of the table,the new value will stay.
the code:

```
var COLUME, VAL;
$('td').click(function() {
    COLUME = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#displaycolumeid').html(COLUME);
    $('#colume1').hide();
    $('#inputName').show();

});


$(".edittd").mouseup(function() {
    return false
});


$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('#colume1').show();
    $('#inputName').hide();
    VAL = $("#inputName").val();
    $("#colume1").html(VAL); 
});​
```

the css:

```
.edittd
{
font-size:14px;
width:200px;
background-color:#ffffcc;
border:solid 1px #000;
padding:4px;
}
.display{
background:red;
    width:110px;
}
```

thanks..

​